# My Idle (idle3) from python installed with homebrew on a mac crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Idle3 (of python3) regularly crashes when in a window and using the middle mousewheel.

There is always the same error left in Terminal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/idle3", line 5, in   main()   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/idlelib/pyshell.py",
>   line 1548, in main
>       root.mainloop()   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1280, in mainloop  self.tk.mainloop(n)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xFF in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>   `

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that brew installed python without tcl-tk, thus using the old tcl-tk from mac-os. This one has a problem interpreting some mousewheel commands.

The solution  : 
`brew reinstall python --with-tcl-tk`

Comment: `--with-tcl-tk` no longer works with the latest brew. Running `brew install python --with-tcl-tk` still points to system Tcl/TK 8.5.9.

Comment: @kakyo you can still monkey patch local python formula to use the right tcl-tk and install it with `--build-from-source`  -  this worked for me with ActiveTcl (but somehow didn't with tcl-tk from brew).

Comment: @ashotyanski how to correctly "monkey patch" the local python formula? The only reference to Tcl/Tk is only to where the Mac's system Tk is added to cflags. Is that where I would change it?

Comment: @Ignat I found my python formula at `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/python.rb`
So you just open it and add your cflags in `install` method.

Also you may find this piece of code particularly interesting - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb#L86